# Smartest way to handle Stripe's Payment Intent and Paypal's Payment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

So my situation is this:
I have a controller method `pay` which will generate a `Stripe\PaymentIntent` and saves it's id in a order which will be stored in the session. Then to the user will be displayed the payment form, where he can choose between Stripe and Paypal:

1. if he choose the Paypal payment, after submitting the form, will be assigned to the session order as `payment_id` the Paypal payment id and he will be redirected to Paypal , and then I'll update the Payment status of that Order using the `payment_id` to find it and using the callback URLs given to Paypal to check check the status.
2. else will be displayed to him the Stripe payment form, and then on submit I'll save the order stored in the session in the Database (note: the PaymentIntent id was previous prefilled in the `pay` method).

**My question is this**: is there a better way to do handle both Stripe and Paypal payment? (i'm just looking for a way, i don't need any sort implementation)
Also because this will generate a Stripe `PaymentIntent` in every case, and if the user choose the Paypal payment, this PaymentIntent wil be ignored and the `payment_id` ovewritten by the Paypal payment id

Comment: @TimLewis removed

Comment: Better, but still not a good fit for Stackoverflow. You're asking for a better way, which is generally a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you haven't posted any code, so... Not sure what you want here.